# How to set up a Poetry project to install module as a runnable Python binary?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have a Python project that I intend to run as a command line utility and I'm managing its build using Poetry. Through `poetry install`, I'm able to install a snapshot of the module and import it within the virtualised environment or run it through `python -m`. However, I want to be able to add it to the shell's path just like how `poetry` itself end up being runnable without necessarily having to invoke it with `python -m`. How do I configure my Poetry project to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poetry provides a relatively easy way to add [executables](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts) via the `pyproject.toml`, using:

The example from the docs is:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
my_package_cli = 'my_package.console:run
```

This will add the `my_package_cli` which executes the `run` function that would be defined in the `my_package.console` module.

So if you use `poetry install` again after adding the above it should work in the poetry environment, or if you `pip install` your project anywhere else, it will also work.

Comment: Cool. I thought the scripts section were only for local dev/build tasks. Thanks!